# Mysql Php select and process one record at a time using transaction and commit

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to select a range of ids from one table and then put them 
through a transaction loop to process a update one record at a time?

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT p_code FROM replenishment ');
$ids = array();

while ($p_code = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $ids[] = $p_code[0];
    foreach($ids as $p_code) {
        mysql_query('SELECT @A:=replenishment.p_code,@B:=replenishment.model
                        from replenishment
                        left join replenishment1 on replenishment1.p_code = replenishment.p_code
                        where replenishment.branch=10
                        and replenishment.p_code=$p_code
                        and replenishment.stock < min

                        and replenishment1.stock > 0

                        group by replenishment.p_code');
        mysql_query('UPDATE replenishment1
                        SET stock = (stock - @B), B5=(b5+@B)  WHERE @A = replenishment1.p_code
                        and replenishment1.stock >= @B');
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc();
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

**Start using PDO or MySQLi.**

Through this you can manage your transaction and make sure that data enters in your database safely.

```
<?php
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2', 
      array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
}

try {  
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $dbh->beginTransaction();

/* You can put your foreach loop over here or you can also do the entire process for single update. It's your choice */

  $dbh->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

It guarantees that no one else will be able to see those changes until they are complete. If something goes wrong, the catch block rolls back all changes made since the transaction was started, and then prints out an error message.

Comment: You don't need the setAttribute function nor do I need the beginTransaction method, or the commit function.